# Stripe iframe not accessible within Dusk component

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I have no problem accessing and filling in the form at the test level:
This works:

```
public function user_can_subscribe()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->visit(new SubscribePage)
                ->waitFor('.__PrivateStripeElement iframe')
                ->withinFrame('.__PrivateStripeElement iframe', function($browser) {
                    $browser->pause(3000)
                        ->keys('input[placeholder="Card number"]', 4242424242424242)
                        ->keys('input[placeholder="MM / YY"]', '0125')
                        ->keys('input[placeholder="CVC"]', '123')
                        ->keys('input[placeholder="ZIP"]', '12345');;
                })
                ->press('@subscribe-button');
        });
    }
```

I'd like to move the stripe form into a Dusk component.
In the component i have:

```
 public function selector()
    {
        return '.__PrivateStripeElement';
    }
```

```
public function fillCardDetails(Browser $browser, $number = '4242424242424242')
    {
        $browser->waitFor('iframe')
                ->withinFrame('iframe', function($browser) use ($number) {
                    $browser->pause(3000)
                        ->keys('input[placeholder="Card number"]', $number)
                        ->keys('input[placeholder="MM / YY"]', '0125')
                        ->keys('input[placeholder="CVC"]', '123')
                        ->keys('input[placeholder="ZIP"]', '12345');;
                });

    }
```

But calling the function from the test does not work:

```
public function user_can_subscribe()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->visit(new SubscribePage)
                ->within(new StripeForm, function (Browser $browser) {
                    $browser->fillCardDetails();
                })
                ->press('@subscribe-button');
        });
    }
```

```
Unable to locate element:
{"method":"css selector","selector":"body .__PrivateStripeElement input[placeholder="Card number"]"}
```

I've tried changing selectors, different timeouts, but can't get it to work.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @HashimAziz nope